# SAPUI5 Uncaught TypeError: jszip is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing a sapui5 application to upload .xlsx file and read data of the uploaded file. And I've followed the instructions in the comment section of the following url

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3782341

And as it mentioned I've added xlsx.js & jszip.js in to the project (libs folder)
and I've changed jszip.js files first few lines of code with following code as mentioned in the above URL

```
!function(e){ if(typeof exports==="object"&& typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=e();}

else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],e);}else{var f;typeof window!=="undefined"?f=window:"undefined"!=typeof global?f=global:"undefined"!=typeof self

&&(f=self),f.JSZip=e();}}(function(){

return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require==="function"&&require;if(!u&&a){return a(o,!0);}

if(i){return i(o,!0);}

throw new Error("Cannot find module'"+o+"'");}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};

t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];

return s(n?n:e);},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r);}return n[o].exports;}var i=typeof require==="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++){s(r[o]);}

return s;})({1:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){

'use strict';

// private property

var _keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
```

Early it worked well when I run the application in web IDE & also when deployed to the sap cloud launch pad.

But today when I check the deployed version of the application again it is not working and gives the following error.

> xlsx.js?eval:11375 Uncaught TypeError: jszip is not a constructor
>       at read_zip (xlsx.js?eval:11375)
>       at Object.readSync [as read] (xlsx.js?eval:11396)
>       at FileReader.reader.onload (Home.controller.js?eval:37)

The error occured in this function of the xlsx.js file

```
function read_zip(data, opts) {
    var zip, d = data;
    var o = opts||{};
    if(!o.type) o.type = (has_buf && Buffer.isBuffer(data)) ? "buffer" : "base64";
    switch(o.type) {
        case "base64": zip = new jszip(d, { base64:true }); break;
        case "binary": case "array": zip = new jszip(d, { base64:false }); break;
        case "buffer": zip = new jszip(d); break;
        case "file": zip=new jszip(d=_fs.readFileSync(data)); break;
        default: throw new Error("Unrecognized type " + o.type);
    }
    return parse_zip(zip, o);
}
```

But the application is working perfectly when I run it using web IDE.

This is how I use the included js libraries

```
jQuery.sap.require("SampleFileApp.libs.xlsx");
jQuery.sap.require("SampleFileApp.libs.jszip");

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("SampleFileApp.controller.Home", {
            handleExcelUpload: function(e) {

            var fileUpload = this.getView().byId("idfileUploader");
            var domRef = fileUpload.getFocusDomRef();
            var file = domRef.files[0];
            this._import(file);

        },

        _import: function(file) {
            var that = this;
            if (file && window.FileReader) {

                //Initialize Reader
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var result = {},
                    data;

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    data = e.target.result;
                    //get workbook data as binary
                    var wb = XLSX.read(data, {
                        type: 'binary'
                    });
                    wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                        var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
                        if (roa.length > 0) {
                            result[sheetName] = roa;
                        }

                    });
                    //Display Uploaded data
                    //that.displayUploadedData(result);
                    //that.displayData(result);
                    that.bindTable(result);
                    return result;

                };

                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

            }

        }
};
```

And also I've added js reference for the xlsx.js in the component.js file

```
jQuery.sap.require("SampleFileApp.libs.xlsx");


sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "SampleFileApp/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("SampleFileApp.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function() {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

Cannot identify any deferences in the code. This is not working only when deployed to the cloud launch pad

Answer (score 0):

Add file /dist/xlsx.full.min.js, instead of xlsx.js. 
https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/blob/master/dist/xlsx.full.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Install jszip libraries in your project node_Modules....using the command

"npm i jszip"

Answer (score -2):

Instiation of files starts from component controller instead index.html,
so declare module paths in component controller:
like this:

```
jQuery.sap.require("com.sap.sbi.jszip");
jQuery.sap.require("com.sap.sbi.xlsx");
```

in component controller.

Comment: so do I need to add xlsx.js & jszip.js in to a lib folder & include them?

Comment: it gives a 404 error 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/resources/com/sap/sbi/jszip.js not found
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/resources/com/sap/sbi/xls not found